# Changing the id of an element using Prototype?

Tags: prototypejs

Lets say I have an element like this:

```
<input id="options_14_text" type="text" onchange="something()" name="options[14]" value="">
```

How could I change its id to options_15_text for example using Prototype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the element and then change its `id` property:

```
​$("options_14_text").id = "options_15_text";​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Or you could use [`writeAttribute`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/writeAttribute/):

```
​$("options_14_text").writeAttribute("id", "options_15_text");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/ZxeTe/). Inspect the DOM to see that the `id` value has changed.

Comment: How would I change the name to someting else? I tried .name, but it did not work.

Comment: @user1540714 - The same way. `.name` or `writeAttribute` should work fine. I just tried it in the example linked to in my answer.